# Error while adding a file to document library with the following code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, development, validation

I am using the following code to add a file to my document library, but it keeps giving me List data validation error (even if the values are correct!)

```
myHashtable.Add("Text","Valid");
myHashtable.Add("Test_x0028_Test_x0029_", "Valid");
myHashtable.Add("Hello_x0028_Hello_x0029_", "Hello");
myHashtable.Add("MY_x0028_MY_x0029_", "MY");

myFile = listFolder.Files.Add(destFile, binFile, myHashtable,false);
```

Any ideas???

[StackTrace}

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)\r\n   
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile, Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64 fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId, Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)\r\n   
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.AddStreamOrBytesInternal(String urlOfFile, Stream file, PutFileOpt fileOpt, String createdBy, String modifiedBy, Int32 createdByID, Int32 modifiedByID, DateTime timeCreated, DateTime timeLast
    Modified, Object varProperties, String checkInComment, Stream formatMetadata, String lockIdMatch, String etagToMatch, SPLockType lockType, String lockId, TimeSpan lockTimeout, Boolean validateRequiredFields, SPVirusCheckStatus& virusCheckStatus, String& virusCheckMessage, String& etagNew, Boolean& ignoredRequiredProps)\r\n   
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Byte[] file, Hashtable properties, Boolean overwrite)\r\n   at Test.CreateDocumentForm(String rootFolder)"
```

Comment: Share the error message with the stack trace please.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis Updated

Comment: What is the error message that goes with that stack trace? Also, have you tried it without (what I presume are) those 3 custom columns you've added?